# Prove that $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous at $x_0 = 1$ ($\delta-\varepsilon$ proof)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, exponential-function, epsilon-delta

Prove that the function $$f(x)=e^x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$ is continuous at $x_0=1$ using the delta epsilon definition of continuous, which is:

$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 (\forall x\in D:|x-x_0|<\delta) |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$$

Since, in this particular context, the limit inside $e^x$ was proved to be convergent for all $x$ using the Bernoulli inequality and monotone convergence theorem, I'm struggling to see how I can apply a delta epsilon proof here.  In my limited experience, I've applied it to nothing more than simple algebraic functions, but this is pretty significantly different.  How do I start?

Comment: Hint: How would you convert a limit to an epsilon delta definition?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$e^x := \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\;\; \mathsf ? $$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You proved previously that the limit is convergent. This means
$$\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\;{s.t.}\;n\geq N\implies\left|e^x-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right|<\epsilon$$
To prove continuity of the defined function, we want to show
$$\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|=\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n - \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{x_0}{n}\right)^n\right|<\epsilon$$
Our approach will be to reduce this to
$$\left|e^x-e^{x_0}\right|<\epsilon$$
which is a well known and easy to prove continuous function. Let's start by choosing $N$ so that the sequence is convergent. Now let's cleverly add zero.
$$\begin{align}\left|\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n - e^x + e^x - \left(1-\frac{x_0}{n}\right)^n\right|&\leq\left|e^x-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right|+\left|e^x-\left(1-\frac{x_0}{n}\right)^n\right|\\&<\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\left|e^x-\left(1-\frac{x_0}{n}\right)^n\right|\\
&=\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\left|e^x-e^{x_0}+e^{x_0}-\left(1-\frac{x_0}{n}\right)^n\right|\\
&<\frac{2\epsilon}{3}+\left|e^x-e^{x_0}\right|\end{align}$$
We want to choose a $\delta$ such that
$$\left|e^x-e^{x_0}\right|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$
Consider the case that $x\geq x_0$, then consider $e^x-e^{x_0}=e^{x_0}\left(e^{x-x_0}-1\right)$. So we can choose a $\delta$ such that
$$e^{x_0}\left(e^\delta-1\right)=\frac{\epsilon}{3}\implies\delta=\ln\left(1+e^{-x_0}\frac{\epsilon}{3}\right)$$
which is what we wanted to show. The same can be shown for $x_0>x$. Note that this $\delta$ is dependent on $x_0$ indicating point-wise continuity.

Edit: Fixed based on Jason DeVito's counterexample.

Comment: What do you mean by "Choose $N$ large enough so that the limit is convergent"?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I meant to say sequence is convergent. Thanks for that. I changed it accordingly.

Comment: There was a mistake in my original post; the limit should have been defined as follows:
$e^x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$
Although this doesn't change your answer drastically, you should be aware of it.

Comment: @MasterYoda:  I'm still not sure what you mean.  The sequence is convergent or not, independent of whether we pick a value for $N$ or not.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks. Changed again. Keep in mind $N$ must be chosen to satisfy the logic statement.

Comment: Something's still not quite right (but I am not sure what).  If, say, I pick $\epsilon$ really really tiny, then $|\epsilon/2 - 1| < .99999$, so I can take $\delta = .9$ when $\epsilon$ is microscopic.  But if I pick an $x\in (1-\delta, 1+\delta)$ like $x = 1.8$ and compute, I get $|e^{1.8} - e^{1}|\approx  3.337 > \epsilon$.  What am I not seeing?  (Also, I feel as though at this point I am just pestering - this will be my last comment about this answer unless you'd really like more feedback from me.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito That is a great observation. You are right. Turns out I was wrong as my solution implied that $e^x$ is uniformly continuous, which it is not. I have fixed that problem with a new solution if you want to check it again.

Comment: Since you asked, here are a few ideas.  1.  I still have no idea what you mean by picking $N$ so that something is convergent.  2.  The long string of inequalities should start with $|e^x - e^{x_0}| = | e^x - (1+x/N)^N + (1+x/N)^N -e^{x_0}|$ or something similar.  Right now, your string begins with $|(1-x/N)^N - (1-x_0/N)^N|$ which is different from $|e^x - e^{x_0}|$ (the latter is what you're trying to prove something about.  3.  I agree that using the usual properties of $e$ and $\ln$ as you did in your approach works.  But I don't know how to prove them using the OPs definition of $e^x$.

Comment: We need to choose $N$ so we can apply $$\left|e^x-\left(1-\frac{x_0}{n}\right)^n\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$ We need to start from $$\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|$$ as that is what the problem is asking us to prove, is it not?

Comment: What I am saying is that your string of inequalities begins with $\left|\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n - e^x + e^x - \left(1-\frac{x_0}{n}\right)^n\right|$ which, after canceling $e^x$, is equivalent to $\left|\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n - \left(1-\frac{x_0}{n}\right)^n\right|$, which is not the same as $\left|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n -  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{x_0}{n}\right)^n\right|$.  The last expression is what you want to show something about.  And I still think some new idea is needed - how does this answer avoid the issue with rldias's answer?

Comment: (I don't know what that new idea is.   Also, really minor, but the terms should look like $(1+x/n)$, not $(1-x/n)$.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some hints that will help you. It's just write it with more details.

Let $x_0\in\mathbb R$ and $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary real numbers.

Notice that
$$|e^x - e^{x_0}| = |e^x - (1+x/n)^n + (1+x/n)^n - (1+{x_0}/n)^n + (1+{x_0}/n)^n - e^{x_0}| \leq |e^x-(1+x/n)^n| + |(1+x/n)^n-(1+{x_0}/n)^n| + |(1+{x_0}/n)^n-e^{x_0}|$$
so a $\epsilon/3$-argument would be a nice idea.

Of course $|e^x-(1+x/n)^n|$ and $|(1+{x_0}/n)^n-e^{x_0}|$ get small enough ($<\epsilon/3$) as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

So it's sufficient to show that $|(1+x/n)^n-(1+{x_0}/n)^n|$ get small enough ($<\epsilon/3$) as $x$ goes to $x_0$.
Well, here we can use the fact that for a fixed $n$ the function $z\mapsto(1+z/n)^n$ is continuous at $x$ (it is a polynomial).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that showing $|(1+x/n)^n - (1+x_0/n)^n|$ gets small as $x\rightarrow x_0$ needs more than just the fact that for fixed $n$, $z\mapsto (1+z/n)^n$ is continuous.  For each $n$, by continuity of polynomials, there is a $\delta_n$ with the property that $|x-x_0|<\delta_n$ implies $|(1+x/n)^n - (1+x_0/n)^n|<\epsilon/3$, but it could be the case that $\delta_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.  (This is what happens, for example, if one uses $z\mapsto z^n$ instead).  What one needs is a uniform $\delta$ which is independent of $n$.

Comment: We can choose $N\in\mathbb N$ so that both $|e^x-(1+x/N)^N|$ and $|e^{x_0}-(1+{x_0}/N)^N|$ are less than $\epsilon/3$ and then work with $z\mapsto(1+z/N)^N$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I may be missing something ;-).  What if you apply your argument to $f(x):= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x^n$, where I'm thinking of $x\in [0,1]$  For each $n$, $f_n(x) = x^n$ is continuous, but $f = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n$ is the discontinuous function which is $0$ on $[0,1)$ and $1$ at $x=1$.

Comment: Ah - I got it:  the issue is not where I said it was earlier.  I agree (now) that once you find an appropriate $N$, that final inequality follows from continunity.  But I'm not sure you can find the $N$ like you want.  The problem is that for each $x$, there is an $N = N(x)$ which makes the term $|e^x - (1+x/n)^n|$ small, but as $x$ varies, this $N$ might blow up to infinity.

Comment: This, in turn, can cause the relevant $\delta$ in the last step to shrink to $0$.  This is a problem because the definition of continuity at $x_0$ begins with "For all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ with the property that for all $x$...." so $\delta$ must be independent of $x$.  My analysis is rusty, so I don't know how to fix it in this particular problem, but the key is that $(1+x/n)^n\rightarrow e^x$ is not just point wise convergence, but uniform convergence.

Comment: Oh I see it now and you're completely right! I don't know how to prove that the family $z\mapsto(1+z/n)^n$ is equicontinuous (or even if it is equicontinuous). Thanks for your appointment

Answer (score 0):

Since you already covered the hard part of showing that the limit of sequence $(1+(x/n))^{n}$ exists for all real $x$, the continuity of the function defined via this limit will not seem that difficult to you.

Establish that $e^{x+y} =e^xe^y$ and then note that $$|e^x-e|=e|e^{x-1}-1|$$ and then use the inequality (you need to prove this too) $$1+x\leq e^x\leq \frac{1}{1-x}$$ for $0<x<1$. This should help you to prove that $e^x$ is continuous at $1$ by finding an appropriate $\delta$.

Let me know if you have difficulty proceeding in this manner and then I will provide more details. As a bonus that inequality mentioned above is fundamental and powerful and can be used to prove that $e^x$ is differentiable everywhere with the derivative equal to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to initially write $\exp(x)$ instead of $e^x$ to lesssen the tempatation to use exponential rules, until we show $\exp(x)$ really is an exponential function.  (I am assuming you have already proved some exponential laws in your class).

Assuming $x > 0$, Set $m = n/x$, so that $m\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.  Substituting this in gives  $\exp(x):=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1 + x/n)^n = \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} (1 + 1/m)^{mx} = [\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} (1+1/m)^m]^x = \exp(1)^x$.  Defining $e:=\exp(1)$, this proves $\exp(x) = e^x$, so it really is an exponential.

We next claim that if $e^x$ is continuous at $x_0 = 0$, then $e^x$ is continuous everywhere.  To see this, choose $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ suppose $\epsilon>0$ is given.  Then $|e^x - e^{x_0}| = |e^{x_0}(e^{x-x_0} - 1)| = e^{x_0}|e^{x-x_0} - 1|$.  By hypothesis, there is a $\delta$ with the property that if $|y|<\delta$, then $|e^y - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{e^{x_0}}$.  Then using this $\delta$, if $y=|x-x_0| < \delta$, then $|e^x - e^{x_0}| = e^{x_0}|e^{x-x_0} - 1|   < e^{x_0}\frac{\epsilon}{e^{x_0}} = \epsilon$, as desired.

We next claim that if $e^x$ is continuous from the right at $x_0$, then it is automatically continuous from the left at $x_0$.  The point is that $e^{x_0}\neq 0$, so $1/e^x $ is continuous from the right at $x_0$.  But $1/e^x = e^{-x}$, so this is the same as being continuous from the left.

Thus, we need only show that $e^x$ is continuous from the right when $x_0=0$.  So, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.  Now, pick $\delta < \min\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon+1}\}$.

Assume $0<x<\delta$.  Then using the binomial theorem, \begin{align*} |e^x - 1| &= |\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1+x/n)^n -1| \\ &= \left|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}\left( \frac{x}{n} \right)^k -1\right|\\ &= \left| \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}\frac{1}{n^k} x^k\right| \end{align*}.

We need to estimate ${n\choose k} \frac{1}{n^k}$.  We get \begin{align*} {n\choose k}\frac{1}{n^k} = \frac{\overbrace{n(n-1)...(n-(k+1))}^{k\ terms}}{k!} \frac{1}{n^k} \\ &\leq \frac{n(n)...(n)}{k!} \frac{1}{n^k} \\ &= \frac{1}{k!}\\ &\leq 1\end{align*}

In particular, since $x> 0$, $$\left| \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}\frac{1}{n^k} x^k\right|\leq \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k\right| = \left|\frac{x}{1-x}\right|,$$ where we use the geometric series formula (which is valid since $|x|<\delta < 1$.)

Now, one easily verifies that $\frac{x}{1-x} < \epsilon$ iff $x< \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$, and since $|x|<\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$.  This completes the proof that $f(x) = e^x$ is continuous.